# Classe em view.py no Django

Tags: python, django

Estou tentando desenvolver um quiz com o django, na minha lógica criei uma classe no view.py, mas agora não sei como fazer referência aos métodos dessa classe no url.py

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Disciplina, Topico, Questao, Teste
from .forms import SelecaoForm



import json

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'freque_play/index.html')

def disciplinas(request):
    """Mostra a lista de todas as Disciplinas."""
    disciplinas = Disciplina.objects.order_by('nome_disciplina')
    context = {'disciplinas' : disciplinas}
    return render(request,'freque_play/disciplinas.html', context)

def disciplina(request, disciplina_id):
    """Mostra a lista de topicos e subtopicos de uma disciplina."""

def novo_teste(request):
    """Mostra o formulário de seleçao de questões"""
    form = SelecaoForm()
    disciplina = Disciplina.objects.all()

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'disciplina': disciplina,
    }
    return render(request, 'freque_play/novo_teste.html',context)

def get_topico(request, disciplina_id):
    disciplina = Disciplina.objects.get(pk=disciplina_id)
    topicos = Topico.objects.filter(disciplina=disciplina)
    topicos_dict = {}
    for topico in topicos:
        topicos_dict[topico.id] = topico.nome_topico
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(topicos_dict), content_type="application/json")



def new_teste(request):
    topico_id = request.POST.get("topico")
    topico= Topico.objects.get(pk=topico_id)
    questoes = Questao.objects.filter(topico=topico)
    respostas = {}
    teste = Teste(questoes, respostas)
    quiz = QuizRun(request,teste)


class QuizRun(request, teste):
    questao_atual = 0

    def __init__(self, request, teste)
        self.display_question(request, questao_atual)

    def display_question(self, request, questao_seq):
        questao = teste.questoes[questao_seq]
        resposta = teste.respostas[questao.id]
        if resposta = ""
            comentar = False
            mensagem = ""
        elif resposta == questao.aCorreta: 
            comentar = True
            mensagem = "você acertou alternativa correta " + questao.aCorreta
        else
            comentar = True
            mensagem = "Resposta errada " + resposta ", alternativa correta " + questao.aCorreta
        context = {
        'questao': questao,
        'comentar' : comentar,
        'mensagem' : mensagem,
        }
    return render(request, 'freque_play/teste.html', context)

    def next_question(self, request):
        if self.questao_atual < len(teste.questoes):
            self.questao_atual = questao_atual + 1
            self.display_question(request, questao_atual)

    def previous_question(self, request):
        if self.questao_anterior > 0:
            self.questao_atual = questao_atual - 1
            self.display_question(request, questao_atual)

    def responder(self, request):
        alternativa = request.POST.get("options")
        questao = teste.questoes[questao_atual]
        if questao.responder(alternativa):
            questao.status = 1
            questao.salve()
            teste.respostas[questao.id] = alternativa
            self.display_question(request, questao_atual)

        else:
            questao.status = 0
            questao.salve()
            teste.respostas[questao.id] = alternativa
            self.display_question(request, questao_atual)
```

urls.py

```
path('responder_teste', views.responder_teste, name='responder_teste'),
    path('next_question', views.next_question, name='next_question'),
    path('previous_question', views.responder, name='previous_question'),
```

(obvio que essas urls não funcionaram, é só um exemplo)
como seria a forma certa de fazer essas urls? Ou não tem como fazer e tem algo errado na minha lógica?

Obrigado
Criei uma classe para armazenar a lista de questões que está no objeto teste, que contém duas listas uma com as questões e outra com as respostas dadas.
Pensei em salvar numa classe para dar acesso a todos os métodos.
Se não criar uma classe, onde devo instanciar esses objetos pra que todos os métodos tenham acesso?
Obrigado

Comment: porque você criou uma classe? Qual o objetivo de usar uma classe nesse caso?

Comment: Sua lógica esta completamente desconsonate com as recomendações do django e até do python, essa classe só faria sentido se estivesse em um pacote com funcoes genericas, se vc quer usar classes nas views (e é recomendado), utilize as [CBV](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/topics/class-based-views/) que são uma mão na roda para CRUD.

Comment: Criei uma classe para armazenar a lista de questões que está no objeto teste, que contém duas listas uma com as questões e outra com as respostas dadas. Pensei em salvar numa classe para dar acesso a todos os métodos. Se não criar uma classe, onde devo instanciar esses objetos pra que todos os métodos tenham acesso? Obrigado

Comment: Pelo codigo que vc apresenta vc esta fazendo CRUD, certo? Então, como eu disse no comentário anterior, crie uma classe (CBV) para cada view, ai vc consegue uma listagem com 3, 4 linhas, um detalhamente com 2 linhas e por ai vai. Tem varios exemplos na internet, [leia esse texto](https://medium.com/nossa-coletividad/class-based-views-no-django-d76b01ed644e), para começar.